# Alternating Background Color by Groups

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a problem that is very similar to this one:
[Excel: Conditional formatting for clusters of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492425/excel-conditional-formatting-for-clusters-of-values).

My restrictions:
No helper column and only two colors should be used.

Is this possible?

Comment: Similar, but not the same. :) Which colors, and what are the conditions? By `alternating`, do you mean change the highlight/color every time a cluster of like values end?

Comment: Specific colors dont matter, red and blue for example.
Alternate in the same way proposed in the linked example. if the values are 123,123,123,456,456,789,789,789,789, I want the background of the rows with 123 to be red, the rows of 456 to be blue and the rows of 789 to be red again.

Comment: whether there should be certainly two colors or can be more?

Comment: Could be more, I think I got a solution:
`=ISODD(SUM(IF(FREQUENCY($A$1:$A1;$A$1:$A1)>0;1)))`
`=ISEVEN(SUM(IF(FREQUENCY($A$1:$A1;$A$1:$A1)>0;1)))`
Dragged down, the second A1 will change to A2, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to answer my own question:

To achieve alternating results, you can count the unique values in all the cells above including the current one.

The following formula achieves this for two alternations:

```
=ISODD(SUM(IF(FREQUENCY($A$1:$A1;$A$1:$A1)>0;1))) 
=ISEVEN(SUM(IF(FREQUENCY($A$1:$A1;$A$1:$A1)>0;1)))
```

You could use `MOD` and `CHOOSE` to allow for virtually an unlimited amount of alternatives.

The formula needs to be dragged down, the second A1 will change to A2, etc.

It is calculation intensive, so it often times takes a long time until all calculations are performed, especially if you got a long list of data.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Good question, is it mandatory? I am not too happy with my own answer as it is very ressource consuming.

Comment: You are correct, I accepted my own answer because it actually does work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a header row the you can probably do this more easily by just counting the rows where the column A value changes from the previous, e.g. select a range starting at A2, like `A2:A100` and apply this formula

`=MOD(SUM(($A$1:$A1<>$A$2:$A2)+0),2)*($A2<>"")`

and to highlight other rows you only need to identify populated rows, i.e.

`=$A2<>""`

The conditions need to be applied in that order

This will work on text values or numbers (or a mix)

change commas to semi-colons depending on regional settings

Comment: Is there really such a big difference between your solution and mine?

Comment: Was not meant as an insult, I was wondering if I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (assuming your column is B and your values start at B3). 
Works with text.

`=ISEVEN(ROUNDDOWN(SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF($B$3:B3,$B$3:B3)),0))`

[See result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1whj.jpg)