# Excel Conditional formatting to highlight duplicate cells multiple colours

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I have a column of numbers which I would like excel to highlight if the numbers are duplicates. However, I want each set of duplicates to be highlighted a different colour. So for example, using the sample data below, I might want all instances of 1111 to be highlighted yellow, all instances of 1122 to be highlighted green and all instances of 1344 to be highlighted red. The colour that the duplicates are highlighted does not really matter, as long as each set of duplicates is a different colour.

I have tried using conditional formatting to highlight the duplicate cells, but it only highlights everything in 1 colour which makes it hard to differentiate between the groups of duplicates when the groups are all contiguous.

```
Column A:

1111
1111
1122
1122
1122
1344
1344
1153
```

Comment: something related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492425/excel-conditional-formatting-for-clusters-of-values

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use conditional formatting and employ different formulas. 
New Rule -> Use a formula to determine which values to format -> $A$2 > 1110 
Then reprat but this time add $A$3>1120 
You can choose which would have precedence. This way you can highlight all the number you want.