# How To Write Macro for highlight filtered rows alternatively

Tags: vba, excel

How to Write Macro for this structure of Formation in Excel To Highlight Filtered rows alternatively.. Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: This is not a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @WNG Is it Ok Now?

Comment: Well I'm not a validator of questions. I still don't understand it, you shall see if other people do. Good luck.

Comment: Edited question to include the graphic.  So basically you want to toggle color when the value changes.

Comment: @S Meaden Yes, you are right

Comment: Ya its pretty good.. But I want it as vba code

Comment: Ok, I got it, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your numbers are divided into chunks of *always* different numbers repetitions, then you could use this VBA code:

```
Sub main()
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim okHighlight As Boolean

    With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))
        For Each item In GetUniqueValues(.Cells).Items
            If okHighlight Then .Range(.Cells(startRow, 1), .Cells(item, 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = 48
            startRow = item + 1
            okHighlight = Not okHighlight
        Next
    End With
End Sub


Function GetUniqueValues(rng As Range) As Dictionary
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim dict As Dictionary

    Set dict = New Dictionary
    With dict
        For Each cell In rng
            .item(cell.Value) = cell.row - rng.Rows(1).row + 1
        Next
    End With
    Set GetUniqueValues = dict
End Function
```

---

a Conditional formatting approach is possible with a helper column

assuming:

- your data are in column A, beginning from row 2
- column B is free

then:

- write the following formula in helper column B cells:

  =IF(A2<>A1,B1+1,0)
- apply conditional formatting to column A with the following formula:

  =INT(B2/2)=B2/2

and choosing the format you like to highlight cells

Answer (score 1):

Here you are friend, replace `Sheet4` with name of your sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim rngOrigin As Excel.Range
    Set rngOrigin = Sheet4.Cells(1, 1)

    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Set rng = Sheet4.Range(rngOrigin, rngOrigin.End(xlDown))

    Dim bToggle As Boolean

    Dim rngLoop As Excel.Range
    For Each rngLoop In rng
        If rngLoop.Row > 1 Then
            If rngLoop.Offset(-1, 0).Value <> rngLoop.Value Then

                bToggle = Not bToggle
            End If
        End If
        rngLoop.Interior.ColorIndex = VBA.IIf(bToggle, 4, 2)

    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Among the many ways to do this, here's another:

```
Option Explicit

Sub colorAltRowGroups()

  With Sheets(1)

    Dim colorCell As Boolean: colorCell = False

    Dim val As String, prvVal As String
    prvVal = .Cells(1, 1).Value

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("A1", .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)):
      val = c.Value
      If (val <> prvVal) Then colorCell = Not colorCell
      If colorCell Then c.Interior.Color = vbYellow
      prvVal = val
    Next

  End With

End Sub
```

EDIT:

If you'd like to color the whole row you can replace the If colorCell statement in the code above with this:

```
If colorCell Then c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot for the code and one more thing i want to know.. to select whole row.. is it possible??

Comment: Awesome Bro.. Will u pls share Some Links and ebook to learn VBA Macro coz i'm Noob in that,, Wil u Help Me ??

Comment: There's a lot on-line.  Here's one for beginners ([link](http://www.excelvbatutor.com/vba_book/vbabook_ed2.pdf))